# Number of line segment on the diagonals of a decagon

Tags: calculus

Consider a convex decagon(10-vertex polygon). Determine the number of line segments on the diagonal of the decagon. Keeping in mind that no 3 diagonals meet at the same point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the" diagonal of the decagon? And isn't it the case that there are 5 diagonals that meet at the center (if the decagon is regular)?

Comment: Are you still here? There are questions for you to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each diagonal is cut by all the diagonals that start on one side of it and end on the other. If no 3 lines meet at a point then the number of segments is 1 more than the number of cuts. So look at all the diagonals from one vertex in turn, and sum the segments.

Comment: So the answer won't be the same for all diagonals.

Comment: Correct. I think the questioner is asking for the total number of all line segments on all diagonals, and the condition that no three diagonals intersect at a point is meant to be a hypothesis---it's true of *most* decagons. But I'm not quite sure enough to edit the question further.

Comment: I hope 199113 will return to us to clarify.